# Proper way of displaying User's Name on the Menu in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am using `ASP.NET/C#`.

I am currently displaying the Logged In User's First Name and Middle Name by making use of `Session`.

Here is the code

**HTML:**

```
<li><a href="#"><%=Session["UserFName"]%>&nbsp;<%=Session["UserMName"]%>&#9660;</a>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
//Call the function which returns User's Name
var userName = userBLL.GetUserName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
if (userName != null)
{
Session["UserFName"] = userName.FirstName;
Session["UserMName"] = userName.MiddleName; 
}
```

**Here is the GetUserName function**

```
public Users_AdditionalInfo GetUserName(string userCode)
{
using (var db = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
var userName = db.Users_AdditionalInfos.Where(user => user.UserCode.Equals(userCode)).SingleOrDefault();
return userName; 
}

}
```

Is using `Session variables` to do what I am trying to do is all right?

What are some other ways that many of you do to achieve this?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Actually there is no need to. You can declare public string fields/properties in your codebehind class and use these fields instead of `Session['UserFName']`.

Comment: @KubaWyrostek Can you just give a simple example if possible , I can cook it up , but I am intersted in how others will do.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just mention ASP.NET, not MVC. Are you using MVC or not?

If not, why don't you put a `Literal` control inside the `<li>` and populate that on page-load

In your aspx something like this:

```
<li><a href ="#"><asp:Literal ID="lt_name" EnableViewState="false" 
 runat="server" Text=""></asp:Literal></a>
```

In page load you do:

```
var userName = userBLL.GetUserName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);  

lt_name.text = userName.Firstname + " " + username.Lastname;
```

Comment: I am not using MVC , could you just elaborate your suggestion.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the example , suppose I want t ouse these names on other pages as well then using Session will be better?What do you recommend.

Comment: If you have the same content (e.g. the menu) on other pages as well I suggest you look into using master pages and put the code there. Otherwise you can use session of course to store the data.

Comment: I am using master page in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with ViewState, because you need value just on page with Menu (you don't need in another page)

```
ViewState["UserFName"] = userName.FirstName;
ViewState["UserMName"] = userName.MiddleName; 

Or with InputHidden
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer , what is the difference between ViewState and Session though.

Comment: Viewstate in order cach data in your page having postback action, but  session offer caching  data throughout your navigation

Comment: You mean ViewState will have data for my particular page and Session will have it for all pages right.

Comment: exactly freebird, for example you need get UserFName in another page , the viewstate can't used, but session yes

Answer (score 1):

**In your codebehind class**

```
public string UserFName = "";
public string UserMName = "";
```

**Code behind where you assign:**

```
//Call the function which returns User's Name
var userName = userBLL.GetUserName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
if (userName != null)
{
this.UserFName = userName.FirstName;
this.UserMName = userName.MiddleName; 
}
```

**And finally in aspx code:**

```
<li><a href="#"><%=UserFName%>&nbsp;<%=UserMName%>&#9660;</a>
```

Please remember that if there are special html characters allowed in usernames - you need to escape those characters before printing them out like that.

Comment: Actually it not very good idea in the long run. ;] The better way to do would be to put simple asp:Label control in place where you want to display UserName and assign this Label's content in codebehind. :]

Comment: Kuba Ok , if I use the name of my user in other pages as well then why not use session itself?Thanks.

Comment: What Pleun has just suggested is a good solution. Please accept his answer.

Comment: Because if you have access to your `DataClasses1DataContext` in every page, then you can always query it for the user names. Putting them into Session is simply unncessessary.

Answer (score 0):

in your aspx page or site master page simply put one label like..

```
    <asp:Label ID="lblLoggedUser" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" Enabled="false"
                        ForeColor="Blue" Font-Size="13px"></asp:Label>
```

fitst take login user value session from login page like this.

```
Session["USER"] =txtusername.text;
```

and your sitemaster.cs page's page_load

```
 lblLoggedUser.text= Session["USER"].tostring();
```